# Download Google Play Services JAR

Tags: android, google-play-services

I have been out of touch with Android for considerably long time. Recently I had to develop an Android module for Appcelerator. I need to use the Google Play services. There is one present under extras folder where the JAR is present. After some search I found that there are also smaller size individual JAR files, for example google-play-services-base.jar and so on. I need to use google-play-services-analytics.jar.

Now the question is that as to from where can I download the JAR file (google-play-services-analytics.jar) and also get to know the version for it. Does it have any dependency on google-play-serivces-base.jar. I know this might be a basic question, but will appreciate the help.

Comment: what is the reason for needing to use the jar file vs using gradle?

Comment: I need to the JAR file to build a module for Appcelerator to implement Google Analytics. I can use the entire big JAR file (~5MB), but I want to use the compact one (google-play-services-analytics.jar) so that there is no conflict with the other google-play-services-*.jar in other modules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the Android SDK manager you can select and download Google Play services. The SDK manager will also tell you the path to your sdk so you can find the jar files. Google Play Services is under Extras in the SDK manager.

As stated in the comment below, the Play Services jar can be found in 
 **/app/build/intermedi‌​ates/exploded-aar/com‌​.google.android.gms/p‌​lay-services-analytic‌​s/9.4.0/jars/classes.‌​jar**
after you do a build of your project.

*Update:* as noted in the latest comment, this method will not work any more. Your best chance of getting a recent jar is by downloading it [the official way](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies.html#gmaven-access). E.g. https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-basement/11.8.0/play-services-basement-11.8.0.aar. You can use it for the `input.files` for `JavaExec` as well as for `-libraryjars` during proguarding.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The thing is that this is the full google-play-services JAR. I need to get hold of the smaller JAR (which are specific to perform certain specific tasks), like google-play-services-analytics.jar, which is responsible only for Google Analytics.

Comment: When you build your project with gradle if you have included your analytics dependency like  compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.3.0" Only the necessary classes should be compiled.

Comment: After a build for instance I can find my compiled Google Play classes in /app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.google.android.gms/play-services-analytics/8.3.0/jars/classes.jar

Comment: Perfect! This was exactly what I was looking for. So there seems to be no straight forward way to get hold of the JAR file but need to use this JAR instead. I will check and confirm. If it works, will mark this as an answer.

Comment: @SeanKelleyx Your answer is incorrect.  Take a look at **google_play_services** folder in sdk/extras directory.  There are no jar files there whatsoever!

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky clearly you didn't read my comments. That's okay, I'll repeat myself. I said if you build your project with gradle and have included you analytics dependency, when you build your app, you can look in the filesystem where your project is under /app/build/intermediates/exploaded-aar/com‌​.google.android.gms/p‌​lay-services-analytic‌​s/8.3.0/jars/classes.‌​jar and the jar is there.But instead you don't read all the comments and down-vote me. whatever.

Comment: @SeanKelleyx You really oughta write your complete answers.  People don't always dig into comments, especially that they can get noisy on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to use the .jar file of google play services you need to use everything is google play services. Google does not provide individual jar files for specific parts of google play services like it does with gradle

Comment: Just unpack the Jar using any unzipping tool, then remove the module that you don't require and then repack.

Answer (score 0):

Try this java google play service .jar file

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/g/Downloadgoogleplayservicesjar.htm

--on Eclipse,

then left click on your project explorer -> under "Java Build Path" 
 
[Screen shoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3Jvw.png)  (image view)

after add external jar, click OK 
you will find the external library under "Referenced Libraries" in workspace explorer,

and continue fingers to rock.... ;)