# Getting 'java.lang.String.toLowerCase()' on a null object reference' in crashlytics report in 'com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbsp.zzabx' class

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, google-play-services, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I have an app and I have integrated Crashlystics library in it which catches fatal issues in app and report back to the developer.

Here's how:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
    }
}
```

Here are dependencies:

```
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.6@aar') {
        transitive = true;
}
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.0'
```

Today, I got a report showing me this error:`Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.toLowerCase(java.util.Locale)' on a null object reference` in `com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbsp.zzabx (Unknown Source)` class. This error happened on a LGE device running android marshmallow.

Full stacktrace from Fabric.io's crashlytics:

```
#0. Crashed: TubeSockReader-1: 0 0 0x0000000000000000
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbsp.zzabx(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbsm.zzabv(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbsm.getThreadFactory(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbsm$2.run(Unknown Source)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

--

Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.toLowerCase(java.util.Locale)' on a null object reference
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbsp.zzabx(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbsm.zzabv(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbsm.getThreadFactory(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbsm$2.run(Unknown Source)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

#0. Crashed: TubeSockReader-1: 0 0 0x0000000000000000
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbsp.zzabx(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbsm.zzabv(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbsm.getThreadFactory(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbsm$2.run(Unknown Source)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

#1. HeapTaskDaemon
       at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.runHeapTasks(VMRuntime.java)
       at java.lang.Daemons$HeapTaskDaemon.run(Daemons.java:355)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

#2. pool-6-thread-1
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
       at java.lang.Thread.parkFor$(Thread.java:1220)
       at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:299)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:198)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2053)
       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1090)
       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1071)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1038)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1098)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

#3. OkHttp ConnectionPool
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
       at com.android.okhttp.ConnectionPool.performCleanup(ConnectionPool.java:305)
       at com.android.okhttp.ConnectionPool.runCleanupUntilPoolIsEmpty(ConnectionPool.java:242)
       at com.android.okhttp.ConnectionPool.-wrap0(ConnectionPool.java)
       at com.android.okhttp.ConnectionPool$1.run(ConnectionPool.java:97)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

#4. TubeSockReader-1
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
       at java.lang.Thread.parkFor$(Thread.java:1220)
       at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:299)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:158)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.awaitDone(FutureTask.java:421)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:163)
       at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsBackgroundWorker.submitAndWait(SourceFile:43)
       at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsController.handleUncaughtException(SourceFile:278)
       at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsController$5.onUncaughtException(SourceFile:262)
       at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.uncaughtException(SourceFile:30)
       at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
       at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)

#5. GAC_Executor[1]
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
       at java.lang.Thread.parkFor$(Thread.java:1220)
       at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:299)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:158)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2013)
       at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:410)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1038)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1098)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzadd.run(Unknown Source)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

#6. Queue
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
       at java.lang.Thread.parkFor$(Thread.java:1220)
       at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:299)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:158)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2013)
       at java.util.concurrent.PriorityBlockingQueue.take(PriorityBlockingQueue.java:510)
       at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.performOperation(SourceFile:197)
       at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.get(SourceFile:236)
       at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.take(SourceFile:65)
       at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.take(SourceFile:46)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1038)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1098)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

#7. Answers Events Handler1
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
       at java.lang.Thread.parkFor$(Thread.java:1220)
       at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:299)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:198)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2053)
       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1090)
       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1071)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1038)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1098)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
       at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.ExecutorUtils$1$1.onRun(SourceFile:75)
       at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.BackgroundPriorityRunnable.run(SourceFile:30)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

#8. GoogleApiHandler
       at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(MessageQueue.java)
       at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:323)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)

#9. main
       at java.lang.Character.isDigit(Character.java:2672)
       at java.lang.Character.isDigit(Character.java:2658)
       at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifierParser.nextInt(Formatter.java:2406)
       at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifierParser.parseArgumentIndexAndFlags(Formatter.java:2329)
       at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifierParser.parseFormatToken(Formatter.java:2298)
       at java.util.Formatter.doFormat(Formatter.java:1071)
       at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:1042)
       at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:1011)
       at java.lang.String.format(String.java:1554)
       at java.lang.String.format(String.java:1528)
       at com.getsportalapp.sportal.SignUpActivity$7.run(SourceFile:599)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5421)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

#10. AsyncTask #2
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
       at java.lang.Thread.parkFor$(Thread.java:1220)
       at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:299)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:158)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2013)
       at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:410)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1038)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1098)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

#11. FinalizerWatchdogDaemon
       at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Thread.java)
       at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Thread.java:1031)
       at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Thread.java:985)
       at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon.sleepFor(Daemons.java:273)
       at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon.waitForFinalization(Daemons.java:284)
       at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon.run(Daemons.java:232)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

#12. GAC_Executor[0]
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
       at java.lang.Thread.parkFor$(Thread.java:1220)
       at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:299)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:158)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2013)
       at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:410)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1038)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1098)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzadd.run(Unknown Source)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

#13. AsyncTask #1
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
       at java.lang.Thread.parkFor$(Thread.java:1220)
       at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:299)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:158)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2013)
       at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:410)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1038)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1098)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

#14. pool-1-thread-1
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
       at java.lang.Thread.parkFor$(Thread.java:1220)
       at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:299)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:158)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2013)
       at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:410)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1038)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1098)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

#15. pool-2-thread-1
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
       at java.lang.Thread.parkFor$(Thread.java:1220)
       at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:299)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:198)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2053)
       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1090)
       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1071)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1038)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1098)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

#16. FirebaseDatabaseWorker
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
       at java.lang.Thread.parkFor$(Thread.java:1220)
       at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:299)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:198)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2053)
       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1090)
       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1071)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1038)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1098)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

#17. pool-3-thread-1
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
       at java.lang.Thread.parkFor$(Thread.java:1220)
       at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:299)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:198)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2053)
       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1090)
       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1071)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1038)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1098)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

#18. Measurement Worker
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:423)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaud$zzd.run(Unknown Source)

#19. Queue
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
       at java.lang.Thread.parkFor$(Thread.java:1220)
       at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:299)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:158)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2013)
       at java.util.concurrent.PriorityBlockingQueue.take(PriorityBlockingQueue.java:510)
       at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.performOperation(SourceFile:197)
       at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.get(SourceFile:236)
       at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.take(SourceFile:65)
       at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.take(SourceFile:46)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1038)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1098)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

#20. FinalizerDaemon
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:423)
       at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:101)
       at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:72)
       at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:185)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

#21. ReferenceQueueDaemon
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
       at java.lang.Daemons$ReferenceQueueDaemon.run(Daemons.java:147)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

#22. Crashlytics Exception Handler1
       at dalvik.system.VMStack.getThreadStackTrace(VMStack.java)
       at java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:580)
       at java.lang.Thread.getAllStackTraces(Thread.java:522)
       at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsController.writeSessionEvent(SourceFile:1092)
       at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsController.writeFatal(SourceFile:831)
       at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsController.access$100(SourceFile:59)
       at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsController$6.call(SourceFile:285)
       at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsController$6.call(SourceFile:278)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
       at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.ExecutorUtils$1$1.onRun(SourceFile:75)
       at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.BackgroundPriorityRunnable.run(SourceFile:30)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

**What is this** error and why am I getting it?

Comment: To generic to ask.

Comment: Please add full stack trace

Comment: @SergGr done. Please see edited question.

Comment: Are you sure your failing build actually uses version 10.2.0 of the services? Surprisingly I can't find (compiled) classes `zzbsm` or `zzbsp` anywhere. Could you check if they are actually a part of your apk? You can get jar from apk using `dex2jar`, see also  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7888102/how-to-extract-code-of-apk-file. If they are inside your apk, could you check from which bundle (aar) they came looking in folders suggested by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35733844/download-google-play-services-jar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you posted a thread dump, which is only slightly helpful, when what is really needed to diagnose the issue is the full stack trace from the exception.

That said, the only Activity that shows up in the thread dump is SignUpActivity, so I'd suggest looking there.

The error is literally from an attempt to call toLowerCase on a null String reference. This can happen, for instance, if you use an AsyncTask, and access a Text field from the background thread, but the Activity has been destroyed (e.g. device rotation).

The bit about  'com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbsp.zzabx' is most likely a red-herring, a side-effect of the crash reporting library.
Look to your own code first.

Also, as previously mentioned, the actual stack trace, if available, would probably be really helpful.

Comment: I never got this exception while my device was connected to android studio and hence I do not have 'the full stack trace from the exception'. I got the error report from Crashlytics and have pasted the stack trace I got from it.

Answer (score 7):

This is a bug in the GMS library.
Tis error occurs on some virtual testing devices from Google (always Nexus 5x API 23 en-US ...)

See this question for further information: [NullPointer on toLowerCase but I don't use that method anywhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43009734/nullpointer-on-tolowercase-but-i-dont-use-that-method-anywhere)

This is the issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37135148